# How to solve "cstring: No such file or directory" when compiling gcc from source?

Tags: linux, gcc

I am trying to compile a gcc from source since I cannot use yum, apt-get and so forth. My steps are simple:

-I download the source GCC (I tried gcc-4.8.4 and gcc-5.3.0) in my pc and I used:

```
  ./contrib/download_prerequisites
```

-After this, I send this my gcc source file to my system using powerPC y Linux.

```
  mkdir objdir
  cd objdir 
  ../gcc-4.6.2/configure --prefix=/usr --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go
  make
```

I have got the next error:

```
   In file included from ../../gcc-4.9.2/gcc/genmddeps.c:19:0:
   ../../gcc-4.9.2/gcc/system.h:205:20: fatal error: cstring: No such file or directory
   # include <cstring>
                ^
   compilation terminated.
   make[3]: *** [build/genmddeps.o] Error 1
   make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/root/build/gcc'
   make[2]: *** [all-stage1-gcc] Error 2
   make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/root/build'
   make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
   make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/root/build'
   make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any idea about what it is going wrong?

Best regards

Comment: Typo in your question `4.6.2` or `4.9.2` ??

Answer (score 2):

Some advice: first, compile (notably for learning purposes) something *simpler* than GCC, e.g. [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) if you never compiled GNU stuff from source code.

Then compile a *recent* GCC (so 5.3 in january 2016) - building issues would be the same with 4.8, and [GCC 5](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/) is better! You need the `gcc` & `libc-dev` &  `g++` & `libstdc++-dev` for your *host* machine (the one running your future cross-compiler). I am not sure your `--prefix=/usr` is a good idea. Consider perhaps a `--program-suffix=-mine` option (otherwise, your system's `/usr/bin/gcc` could be overwritten, which you don't want to happen)

You could leave the default `--prefix=/usr/local` and later add appropriately `/usr/local/bin/` into your [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29)

Comment: I second the comment about not using `--prefix=/usr`, certainly not until you've done this sufficiently often that you're confident you know the drill and how it all works.  Personally, I keep a `/opt/gcc` directory and install different versions in version-named directories (eg `/opt/gcc/v5.3.0`, where you're not obliged, or even necessarily recommended, to use the `v`).  My PATH setting script chooses the directory of the most recent version automatically — for GCC and other versioned software — so I build and install a new version and end up using it automatically.